# Partition a list to element and the rest in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I got a list in Kotlin, and want to divide this list in one element and the others elements. I could do it like:

```
 val list = listOf(1,2,3,4)
 val (two, others) = list.partition { it == 2 }
 
 print(two.first()) // 2
 print(others)      // [1, 3, 4]
```

Is there a way to write this more elegant? I am looking for something like:

```
 // KOTLIN PSEUDO CODE
 val list = listOf(1,2,3,4)
 val (two, others) = list.partition { it == 2 }.mapFirst { it.first() }
 
 print(two)    // 2
 print(others) // [1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Does the list contain only unique elements? And do you always know that there is a `2` in the list? If so, can't you just use `filter` instead? You already *know* the single element that is going to be removed, so you can do `val (two, others) = Pair(2, list.filter { it == 2 })`.

Comment: @Sweeper this example shows simplified code of course :P. In reality I am using complex objects instead of simple integers. So you would end up with `val (elem, others) = Pair(list.find { <predicateIsTrue> }, list.filter { <predicateIsWrong> })` which does not show the intention of the code clearly anymore. But nice one nonetheless!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform intermediate results using `let` extension

```kotlin
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4)
val (two, others) = list.partition { it == 2 }.let { it.first.first() to it.second }

println(two)
println(others)
```

Output:

```
2
[1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: While this is the correct answer, it is important to note that this will crash if _it_ is not found in _list_.

Answer (score 4):

Amended @Nikolai's answers to make it null safe:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

val (two, others) = list
  .partition { it == 2 }
  .let { (f, s) -> f.firstOrNull() to s }

println(two)
println(others)
```

Now for an *it* which is not in *list* the value of *null* will be returned.